# How to Get ID Equal To Users Sign Up

Tags: php

I do not know where to start from. Bottom line, I have a website and inside there are features private messages (chat)

Here I would like to send short messages via chat automatically to any new members who sign up.

This idea arose when I tried to remove the id username registered. Apparently after new members, coincidentally the same as the ID the user should I ever delete ID, personal messages belonging to someone else appeared on her account. I think this is still an opportunity to be exploited.

However, I may not be able to send messages automatically to every ID that is different, for example 1, 2, 3 and so on.

So, is there a solution for this project?

Comment: Why don't you send the message on the signup event? as soon as the user signs up just send the message

Comment: How is your database structured? Can you post code snippets? Usernames must be unique so you can get the id by username. You could also use the mail address as login -ame.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message for to a user when they sign up shouldn't be too complicated, I developed something similar for my site. The "ID" value of your Users database should be an **auto increment**, so that ID's would go 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on.

I store messages in a PMs database with a SenderID, ReceiverID, Title, Body and Time. When users sign up and their new account is inserted into the database, I run the following query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO PMs (SenderID, ReceiveID, Title, Body, time) VALUES('1','$FU->ID','Example Title','Example Body' ,'".$now."')");
```

**You will need to find the User before sending the message if using this method.** The easiest way to get the ID of the user who signs up is to run a query to find any user with the username submitted through the registration form, then you can select their ID and send them a message.

*You need to ensure that you are running the insert message query after the account is created.*

This method is the quickest and most effective, although you may have to **take a look at your database structure** and alter it to work with this easier method.